# How do I add transition/animation to slider of images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add a transition effect when the image changes?

When the array loops through images, how do I add a transition so that its more smooth.

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3000;


images[0] =  'test.jpg';
images[1] =  'test1.jpg';
images[2] =  'test2.jpg';


function changeImg() {
    document.slide.src = images[i];

    if(i < images.length - 1) {
        i++
    } else {
        i = 0;

    }



    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

window.onload = changeImg;
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-full-screen-slideshow-with-vanilla-javascript--cms-34624) will help.

Answer (score 1):

My easiest way to do it is putting all the images into 1 wrapper.
Then use loop to set active image by element index.
Something like this

```
<style>
  .wrapper { position: relative; }
  .wrapper img {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .wrapper img.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src={images[0]} />
  <img src={images[1]} />
  <img src={images[2]} />
  <img src={images[3]} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is called *cross-fading*, this is a possible duplicate of [How can I smoothly transition CSS background images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194465/how-can-i-smoothly-transition-css-background-images)

But a more detailed guide that worked for me in the past can be found here.
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Keep in mind that you might have to take browser compatibility into consideration if you go the CSS route. Properties such as the -webkit CSS extension is just one of many.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways I found is using `w3.css`.

In your html code add these lines.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <img  class="w3-animate-fading" name="slide" src="" width="800" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The class parameter in your image tag will call the predefined css animations deom w3.css file.
There are many more options such as slide right, slide left etc. You can view them all [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp)

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/gshanbhag525/pen/yLaVoBQ)